# Slim still handling errors even if set not to

Tags: php, slim

Here is my main Slim app instantiation code:

```
$slimSettings = [
    'settings' => [
        'displayErrorDetails' => false,
        'routerCacheFile'     => false  # Settings::ABSPATH . '/tmp/route.cache'
    ],
];

# Initialize
$app = new \Slim\App( $slimSettings );

# Create container
$container = $app->getContainer();

# Register component on container
$container[ 'view' ] = function( $container ) {
    $renderer = new \Slim\Views\PhpRenderer();
    $renderer->setAttributes( [ 'absPath' => Settings::ABSPATH ] ); # Variable accessible from all templates

    return $renderer;
};

# Remove error handling from slim, so custom error handling is used.
unset( $app->getContainer()[ 'errorHandler' ] );
```

You can see that the last line is supposed to unset the errorHandler.
Yet, in a controller for example I declare a function with:

```
public function index( $request, Response $response )
```

I forgot to set the 'Response' use statement, so it created an error (easily fixed but that's not the point). But this error was handled by slim. Why is that ? Isn't it supposed not to handle errors from the unset statement ?

UPDATE: error:

Details

```
Slim Application Error
The application could not run because of the following error:

Type: TypeError
Message: Argument 2 passed to Rib\Src\Controllers\HomeController::index() must be an instance of Rib\Src\Controllers\Response, instance of Slim\Http\Response given
File: /Users/ME/Documents/Apps_And_Sites/PHP_Apps/ribklein/src/Controllers/HomeController.php
Line: 19
```

Comment: Could you post the error you received here.

Comment: @meun5 Message updated with error.

Comment: Does `Rib\Src\Controllers\Response` extend `Slim\Http\Response`?

Comment: No. It seems it tries to guess what the 'Response' in the function argument should be if I don't specify it with a use statement. When I do and specify the slim response, all is fine. Anyway I don't see why it handles any error at all if disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Argument 2 passed to Rib\Src\Controllers\HomeController::index() must be an instance of Rib\Src\Controllers\Response, instance of Slim\Http\Response given

This is a namespace declaration error.Answer

In your controller file (`HomeController`) at the top add this:

```
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;
```

**UPDATE**

Sorry, I misread the question. So, you want to know why the error was handled by Slim.

This is because the error is a PHP Runtime error. And Slim has special handler for that. In container it is stored under the `phpErrorHandler` key. By default it returns a `500` response code, and, of course, you can define your own error handler.

Therefore, to disable Slim's handling of PHP errors, unset `$container['phpErrorHandler']`.

*Important note:* This handler is PHP7+ only, since [PHP Error class was introduced in PHP7.0](http://php.net/manual/en/class.error.php).

You can read more about subject [here](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/handlers/php-error.html).

Comment: Problem is not error. It's why slim catches it even if set not to.

Comment: Thanks but isn't unset( $app->getContainer()[ 'errorHandler' ] ); supposed to disable slim handling of ALL errors ?

Comment: No, `errorHandler`, and `phpErrorHandler` are different handlers.

Comment: OK, I unset phpErrorHandler specifically and now slim doesn't take care of it. Please update your answer just adding to unset specifically phpErrorHandler and i'll select it.

Answer (score 0):

From the error output you posted it looks like that Slim did not handle the error and instead the default php error handler was used.

A Slim error output would look something like this:

```
Slim Application Error

The application could not run because of the following error:
Details
Type: TypeError
Message: Argument 1 passed to Sleeti\Controllers\Authentication\a() must implement interface Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface, array given, called in C:\Source\Web\PHP\Apps\SlimPomf\src\Controllers\Authentication\AuthenticationController.php on line 62
File: C:\Source\Web\PHP\Apps\SlimPomf\src\Controllers\Authentication\AuthenticationController.php
Line: 58
Trace

#0 C:\Source\Web\PHP\Apps\SlimPomf\src\Controllers\Authentication\AuthenticationController.php(62): Sleeti\Controllers\Authentication\a(Array)
#1 [internal function]: Sleeti\Controllers\Authentication\AuthenticationController->postLogin(Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response), Array)
#2 C:\Source\Web\PHP\Apps\SlimPomf\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\Handlers\Strategies\RequestResponse.php(41): call_user_func(Array, Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response), Array)
#3 C:\Source\Web\PHP\Apps\SlimPomf\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\Route.php(340): Slim\Handlers\Strategies\RequestResponse->__invoke(Array, Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response), Array)
#4 C:\Source\Web\PHP\Apps\SlimPomf\src\Middleware\GuestMiddleware.php(27): Slim\Route->__invoke(Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response))
#5 [internal function]: Sleeti\Middleware\GuestMiddleware->__invoke(Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response), Object(Slim\Route))
#6 C:\Source\Web\PHP\Apps\SlimPomf\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\DeferredCallable.php(43): call_user_func_array(Object(Sleeti\Middleware\GuestMiddleware), Array)
#7 [internal function]: Slim\DeferredCallable->__invoke(Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response), Object(Slim\Route))
#8 C:\Source\Web\PHP\Apps\SlimPomf\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\MiddlewareAwareTrait.php(67): call_user_func(Object(Slim\DeferredCallable), Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response), Object(Slim\Route))
#9 C:\Source\Web\PHP\Apps\SlimPomf\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\MiddlewareAwareTrait.php(116): Slim\Route->Slim\{closure}(Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response))
#10 C:\Source\Web\PHP\Apps\SlimPomf\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\Route.php(316): Slim\Route->callMiddlewareStack(Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response))
#11 C:\Source\Web\PHP\Apps\SlimPomf\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\App.php(438): Slim\Route->run(Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response))
#12 C:\Source\Web\PHP\Apps\SlimPomf\src\Middleware\LocalizationMiddleware.php(29): Slim\App->__invoke(Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response))
#13 [internal function]: Sleeti\Middleware\LocalizationMiddleware->__invoke(Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response), Object(Slim\App))
#14 C:\Source\Web\PHP\Apps\SlimPomf\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\DeferredCallable.php(43): call_user_func_array(Object(Sleeti\Middleware\LocalizationMiddleware), Array)
#15 [internal function]: Slim\DeferredCallable->__invoke(Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response), Object(Slim\App))
#16 C:\Source\Web\PHP\Apps\SlimPomf\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\MiddlewareAwareTrait.php(67): call_user_func(Object(Slim\DeferredCallable), Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response), Object(Slim\App))
#17 C:\Source\Web\PHP\Apps\SlimPomf\src\Middleware\LoggerMiddleware.php(36): Slim\App->Slim\{closure}(Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response))
#18 [internal function]: Sleeti\Middleware\LoggerMiddleware->__invoke(Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response), Object(Closure))
#19 C:\Source\Web\PHP\Apps\SlimPomf\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\DeferredCallable.php(43): call_user_func_array(Object(Sleeti\Middleware\LoggerMiddleware), Array)
#20 [internal function]: Slim\DeferredCallable->__invoke(Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response), Object(Closure))
#21 C:\Source\Web\PHP\Apps\SlimPomf\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\MiddlewareAwareTrait.php(67): call_user_func(Object(Slim\DeferredCallable), Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response), Object(Closure))
#22 C:\Source\Web\PHP\Apps\SlimPomf\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\MiddlewareAwareTrait.php(116): Slim\App->Slim\{closure}(Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response))
#23 C:\Source\Web\PHP\Apps\SlimPomf\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\App.php(332): Slim\App->callMiddlewareStack(Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response))
#24 C:\Source\Web\PHP\Apps\SlimPomf\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\App.php(293): Slim\App->process(Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response))
#25 C:\Source\Web\PHP\Apps\SlimPomf\public\index.php(5): Slim\App->run()
#26 {main}
```

Comment: No no, it shows all what your print. To gain space I only posted the error target, but I do see the slim error text and whole stack trace. I updated my post.